# Win 8.1 ComboBox Display the "ToString" Function Result when the SelectedItem is Null or Empty String

Tags: c#, windows-8, combobox, windows-8.1

I have an XAML Combobox like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
```

And the bond data items are defined below (the `DefaultViewModel` is a `ObservableDictionary` object used for data binding):

```
DefaultViewModel["Items"] = new[] {"This", "That", null};
```

The data binding is working fine. When I click the "This" or "That" options, the selected values are displayed correctly; however when I click the empty option (namely the `null`), the `ToString()` result of the bound object (`TestApp.Common.ObservableDictionary`) is shown instead of just being empty.

What is going wrong here? Thanks!